# Using reflection to set a property of a control

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I am using reflection to assign properties for controls as the control properties are stored in the database.And I am facing issues with following situation.

I have raddateinput control and it is having a property `DateInput.DataFormat` and when I tried get the propertyinfo for the using following code it returns as null.

```
ctrl.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName.Split('.').FirstOrDefault(), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .GetType().GetProperty(propertyName.Split('.').LastOrDefault())
```

`ctrl` is a Control. `propertyName` is `DateInput.DataFormat`

Comment: Split this up so you can debug it and figure out where it breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the solution with the following code.

```
    Private void SetProperty(Object ctrl, string propertyName, string value)
    {
        string name = propertyName.Split('.').First();
        PropertyInfo property = ctrl.GetType().GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (name != propertyName)
        {
            ctrl = property.GetValue(ctrl, null);
            SetProperty(ctrl, propertyName.Replace(string.Concat(name, "."), string.Empty), value);
            return;
        }
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(property.PropertyType);
        if (converter != null && converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(String)))
                property.SetValue(ctrl, converter.ConvertFrom(value), null);
    }
```